# Codigniter flashdata sometime doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am redirecting to another page to show flashdata but sometimes flashdata doesn't show.

**Controller:**

`$this->session->set_flashdata('success','successfully done')'
 redirect ('main/dashboard');`

**View:**

```
if($this->session->flashdata('success')){
  echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
}
```

Comment: how does controller function dashboard() look like? is there any call to a model?

Answer (score 0):

Check `flashdata is set or not inside if statement`

```
if($this->session->flashdata('success') !=""){
  echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
}
```

OR

```
if($_SESSION['success'] !=""){
  echo $_SESSION['success'];
}
```

Another procedure

```
$_SESSION['item'] = 'value';
$this->session->mark_as_temp('item', 300);
$_SESSION['item'] = 'value';
```

Hope it will work fine

Comment: Try your code, but same problem happen. Sometime flashdata show, and sometime not showing. I think Codigniter have some issues in flashdata.

Comment: Instead of `redirect try $this->load->view('main/dashboard');`